# Ubuntu 16.04, RX 480, AMDGPU-Pro, monitor broken?

Tags: 16.04, graphics

So I've got a really strange problem here. I have an RX 480, with three monitors hooked up. One DVI-D, HDMI and DisplayPort. All where working, but I wanted the monitors display height aligned a bit so I was messing with xrandr's --pos command and I entered something "wrong" apparently. My DisplayPort monitor appears to have broken from this, as it won't show a signal anymore. It doesn't show up connected in any way to the computer anymore -- not even in the bios where it worked previously. I've tried unplugging-replugging the power and connection to the computer, removing and reinstalling the AMDGPU-Pro drivers, deleting monitors.xml ... pretty much everything I could think of but I can't get the monitor to work at all anymore. The DVI and HDMI monitors still work fine and the driver is definitely working otherwise.. could xrandr and these drivers have seriously broken this monitor?? That seems bizarrely unlikely from just --pos

I don't have windows so I can't test in there...

dmesg shows the following possibly interesting but indecipherable errors on the displayport..

```
[    0.852451] [drm] [Conn_Detect]  [DP-1] Rx Caps: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ^
[    0.883877] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    0.963847] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    1.091954] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    1.271866] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    1.504231] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    1.583914] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    1.711894] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    1.891906] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    2.124297] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    2.203928] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    2.331981] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    2.511988] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    2.748337] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    2.831967] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    2.963976] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    3.147979] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx4 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    3.380091] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    3.459581] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    3.587580] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    3.767607] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    3.999990] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    4.079624] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    4.207625] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    4.387637] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    4.620177] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    4.699669] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    4.827668] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    5.007680] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    5.244001] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    5.327699] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    5.459721] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    5.643721] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx2 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    5.875848] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    5.955487] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    6.083499] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    6.263504] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR3x1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    6.495900] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    6.575537] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    6.703539] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    6.883554] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBR2x1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    7.115867] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    7.195581] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    7.323585] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    7.503591] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] HBRx1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    7.740129] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    7.823612] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    7.955633] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
[    8.139657] [drm] [Conn_LKTN]    [DP-1] RBRx1 fail VS=0, PE=0^
```

Comment: It does sound like your monitor is kaput, as I agree that I'd seriously doubt that xrandr would break it (just from trying to set position).  If you have a liveusb you could try boot to a live environment and see if the monitor is recognised there but if bios doesn't recognise it anymore it's probably done for. Is it an old monitor? If not see if it's still under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I tried booting off of a USB key but it didn't have drivers to support the RX 480. ;( Its a new 1440p BenQ GW2765. I fixed it by plugging it into the computer via HDMI -- then that worked. So I plugged it back into DP and it continued to work.

My guess is that this monitor has some kind of buggy behavior with it and needs to be treated with kid gloves. Well, it was cheap for a 27 inch 1440p, guess I know why lol.